Why does robocopy /MOVE attempt to delete non-empty folders?
I just ran
Robocopy.exe C:\Users\Greedo'D:\Small Computer\All Images and Videos' *.gif *.bmp *.xcf *.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.cr2 *.tiff  /XD .* AppData /XF .* /MOVE

To move image files from my user over to an external hard drive. Note I didn't /S to recurse but I intend to, hence the folder exclusions. Without /S, I got an error after running:
2024/10/22 17:02:26 ERROR 32 (0x00000020) Deleting Source Directory C:\Users\Greedo\
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

Why is robocopy trying to delete that folder, it contains lots of non-image stuff still. I have tried robocopy /? and it says

   /MOV :: MOVe files (delete from source after copying).
  /MOVE :: MOVE files AND dirs (delete from source after copying).


but doesn't specify whether it will delete dirs if they contain a mix of files matching and not matching the filter.
